# If I change servers on AstroNest will I lose any progress?

Tags: ios, astronest

I have an account on the **Orion** server and I've noticed that many people seem to be jumping ship (it had a high population when I joined last week and now it is medium).

I'm wondering **if I change servers, will I lose any progress?**

Mainly concerned about my fleets, planets and resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I changed servers I had to create a new nation so you do lose everything but I can still go back to my old server to my old nation. I am on an ipad.

Comment: Confirmed. I did this and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will loose everything after changing the server. You have to start from the zero. So you have to be ready to take a loss after changing server.

Comment: It's not so much that you lose everything, it's just that starting a new server starts your progress from scratch *within that new server*. You can return to your old server at anytime to continue where you left off. Each sherbet has its own progress state.